# I Dig it (iPhone) - Center of the earth achievement

Tags: achievements, i-dig-it

I've got most of the achievements in I Dig It but am stuck on Center Of The Earth.  I've played the Center of The Earth campaign mode, and reached the bottom, and have played Special Freeplay: Center of the Earth as well and got to the bottom there.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**[Center of the Earth](http://app-lesauce.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/idig-it-strategy-guide-and-achievement.html)**

> Jules Verne would be proud (The center of the earth is located at 2080 feet deep. You break through at 2040 feet. Be sure to bring
>   plenty of dynamite as there are nothing but rocks for the last 40-60
>   feet.)

Comment: yeah, I can google cheers http://app-lesauce.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/idig-it-strategy-guide-and-achievement.html - that doesn't really answer my question though.

Comment: you asked what are you missing, and this is all the possibilities, only you know what have you done so far

Comment: Fair enough, should have said that :) cheers

Comment: Celta, they are not asking what badges they're missing. "What am I missing?" is asking for why they don't have the Center of the Earth badge after the actions they describe. "What am I missing?" is a colloquial expression that is asking what part of understanding they are missing.

Comment: i didn't understand the down vote..i answered the question, explained the center of the earth badge and also have additional information in other badges so other people can know.

Comment: The OP says you have not answered the question. If you think you did, you should make that info clearer. Deleting unrelated info is one way you can make the answer you're trying to give clearer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie excluded information for the answer to be clearer, but the seems to be no more additional information to the conclusion of the badge

Comment: We don't just quote other pages on the Internet here. We explain why the problem is happening and how to fix it. I'm not sure how this answer helps, because a quote without explanation isn't very clear. In your own words, how does that quote solve the problem? Right now I can only guess: is the problem that he didn't use dynamite, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think i may have the answer to this:  I played the Center of the Earth campaign mode again, and noticed afterwards that i now had the achievement. (not sure why i didn't first time out).  I think that maybe you don't get some of the achievements in Special Freeplay mode, as i just got a 20x combo in Center of the Earth Freeplay, but it didn't give me the achievement for that either.